# Remove-AzureVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection has no effect

Tags: powershell, azure, vpn

I'm trying to delete the VPN connection (ARM) since there's an issue with it (no shared key displayed when using Get-AzureVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection). I execute the command with -ResourceGroupName and -Name, it asks for confirmation and goes on to delete the connection. But once the delete is complete, it's still listed when i Get-AzureVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection -ResourceGroupName. Same result when I use -Force.

Has anyone ever encountered that and how did you manage to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

It was a back-end issue that was fixed on 07/18/2015. Deleting those objects now work.